# VBA post-запрос на Frankfurt Boerse

Tags: javascript, post, vba

Привет всем! 
Задача стоит выгрузить исторические котировки по ценной бумаге с сайта Франкфуртской биржи за период. Например, по вот этой бумаге - http://en.boerse-frankfurt.de/stock/pricehistory/Tesla-share/FSE/28.8.2017_28.9.2017#Price History На сколько я понял из javascript кода сайта, там идет post-запрос на сервер, формируемый функцией requestHistoricPrice():

```
function requestHistoricPrice() {
        var requestedStockMarket = "";
        if ($('#historic-prices-stock-market').length > 0) {
            requestedStockMarket = $('#historic-prices-stock-market').val();
            if (requestedStockMarket === '') {
                requestedStockMarket = 'ETR';
            }
            requestedStockMarket += '/';
        }
        var requestedStartDate = $('#historic-prices-start-day').val() + "." + $('#historic-prices-start-month').val() + "." + $('#historic-prices-start-year').val();
        var requestedEndDate = $('#historic-prices-end-day').val() + "." + $('#historic-prices-end-month').val() + "." + $('#historic-prices-end-year').val();

        var decodedUri = decodeURIComponent('%2fstock%2fpricehistory%2fTesla-share%2f');
        var dateRange = requestedStartDate + "_" + requestedEndDate;

        var actionUrl = "";
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if ($("#derivative-mastertype").val() !== "") {
            actionUrl = decodedUri + dateRange + hash;
        } else {
            actionUrl = decodedUri + requestedStockMarket + dateRange + hash;
        }

        $('#submitForm').attr('action', actionUrl);
        $('#submitForm').submit();
    };
```

Подскажите, как сделать на VBA post-запрос на сервер, чтобы получить запрашиваемые данные?

Comment: Откройте консоль хрома, найдите запрос, посмотрите, какой тип запроса, какие хедеры используются,  какие параметры отправляют.

Comment: Похоже, там не используется `AJAX`, а вся страница приходит целиком. Вам потом придется парсить ее. Вы точно этого хотите?)

Comment: Собственно, я могу сделать так, чтобы парсить страницу непосредственно из браузера в скрытом режиме. К сожалению это долго и постоянно происходят глюки (например не удается закрыть сам браузер после окончания парсинга, что приводит к снижению производительности в целом). Поэтому, я хочу по сути найти возможность парсить котировки из текста с информацией о котировках, который пересылает сервер на пользовательскую страницу. С Московской биржей мне это сделать удалось. Там информация пересылается в формате json и ее легко парсить. А вот с франкфуртской биржей пока не получается.

Comment: Раз надо парсить сайт - надо парсить! Хотя и не благодарное это дело.